# Identify users using self generated certificates

Tags: java, servlets, x509certificate

I have an requirement to develop a security functionality that will generate a X509 certificate, send it to the user so he/she can import it into the browser and the app will require this certificate for authentication. Do you think this is doable/reasonable and could you give me some hints on how to generate certificates and provide them for downloading to be imported. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An SSL Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security6.html) frem teh google, that should show you what you need. If that's not enough, can you expand your question?

Comment: Do you think this is reasonable? And wouldn't it be easy for others to create such certificates and lie the authentication logic?

Comment: Why don't you get a real cert from a CA and then use it on your server so the users don't need to do anything? That's more secure and less error prone.

Comment: I don't need just a SSL to secure the channel. What i need is for users to import certificates into their browsers for authentication instead of user/pass.

Comment: It depends on what your requirements are, but this means that anyone who gets one of these files will be able to access your system. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I guess this is acceptable, because the same counts for username+password too.

Comment: I think you can google around for how to make a self-signed cert and then create the file for the users, there are lots of articles for that.